# In angular 2 how to communicate between two components?

Tags: angular

Suppose both components are using the same data source (for view and edit). And if one component changes the data I need to instantly reflect it on the other or vice-versa.

Comment: I got the answer. I was loading the data source component via the viewBindings in different views. So whenever I injected it to the component they were receiving different instance of the data source.

Comment: When I placed the data source inside the "bindings" array of the bootstrapped component(main component) it started injecting the same instance to all the child components.

Comment: They are deprecated now ..

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way of doing that now.

You can use **Events** API in angular. [Click here for more details on Events.](https://angular.io/api/router/Event)

Following is example I am currently using.

> import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

Usage :

```
constructor(public events: Events) {

/*=========================================================
=  Keep this block in any component you want to receive event response to            =
==========================================================*/

// Event Handlers
events.subscribe('menu:opened', () => {
  // your action here
  console.log('menu:opened');
});

events.subscribe('menu:closed', () => {
  // your action here
  console.log('menu:closed');
});

}

/*=====================================================
= Call these on respective events - I used them for Menu open/Close          =
======================================================*/


menuClosed() {
// Event Invoke
  this.events.publish('menu:closed', '');
}

menuOpened() {
// Event Invoke
  this.events.publish('menu:opened', '');
}
}
```